# trying to get all the GPO's related to the OU with invoke command

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke, gpo

I have a this set of code:

```
#Find the OU with the selected Canonical name and save it to this variable
$OUObject = Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock {Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter *  -Property CanonicalName | Where-Object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $using:listBox2.SelectedItem}}
```

So after this code i get a an OU stored in a variable $OUObject.
i now want to get all the gpo's linked to this ou.
so my next step is this:

```
$test = $OUObject.LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
```

and now $test hold all the gpos linked to its ou. problem now is i want to get them by name. so i can do this:

```
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock {get-gpo -guid $test}
```

but i will get this error: 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock {get-gpo -guid $test} 
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Guid'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-GPO], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGpoCommand
    + PSComputerName        : DC01

so i look at $test and this is what it holds:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $test
cn={5873971D-F689-4E83-8AFA-389FDD7F34CD},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=bla,DC=local
cn={2B7F8931-038E-46BC-B1DB-FBFA86097C08},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=bla,DC=local
cn={C74CADA1-B609-44A3-8D3C-F733CF3112E2},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=bla,DC=local
```

so what i acually need is to past to the get-gpo command only the part inside the cn{..}

if i hardcode for example and do this:

```
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock {get-gpo -guid 5873971D-F689-4E83-8AFA-389FDD7F34CD}
```

i get the result right.
can anyone help me achive this please?

Comment: `{get-gpo -guid $test}` -> `{get-gpo -guid $using:test}`

Comment: that was a type of mine. if i do {get-gpo -guis $using:test} i will get an error cuz look at $test, i need to substring it somehow and pass it, i need to cut the first part "cn=" and before the "},cn=poli...

Comment: `$test | Select-Object -ExpandProperty cn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex `-replace` operator to extract the GUID from the DN, then pass the value to `Invoke-Command` using the `$using:` modifier:

```
$GUIDs = $test -replace '^cn=(\{[0-9a-f-]+\}).*$'
Invoke-Command -Session $s { $using:GUIDs |ForEach-Object { Get-GPO -Guid $_ } }
```